# a hyperbolic summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

Find the value of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sinh 2^k}$$

Numerical approximations gives me a value of $\frac{2}{e^2-1}$.

I tried to write the sum as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh 2^k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2e^{-2^k(1+2n)}$$

I don't see how to calculate this expression.

Comment: Apparently, it's $\coth(1)-1=\dfrac2{e^2-1}.$

Answer (score 8):

It is a telescopic series. The identity:
$$\coth(x)-\coth(2x)=\frac{1}{\sinh(2x)}\tag{1}$$
gives:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sinh(2^k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\coth 2^{k-1}-\coth 2^{k}\right)=\coth 1-\coth(\infty)=\color{red}{\coth 1-1}.\tag{2}$$